# I have interview for QA position and I found a few bugs on the company's website.Should I mention them in the interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, ethics

So that's basically it, I found a few bugs on the company's website.Should I mention them or say I'll send the data via email or this will make me appear in a negative way?

From my perspective(If I would be the hiring manager) I would be amazed if someone took effort to look for bugs and that would be somewhat of a plus.

Comment: Thank you so much.Very much this, but I still don't get why everyone paints it in a negative manner.I would welcome this proactive approach,especially if that was QA or some related field.Also, my situation is way different, the website is up for several years now, but I'll use your advice.

Comment: That's a good advice.I appreciate that.Kudos to you :).+1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard to say.   They could take you for a know-it-all if you did that.

Honestly...I've worked in QA...and I've participated in hiring and interviewing.    Chances are, they honestly don't really care about the company website.   QA typically doesn't go and proactively look for errors or bugs on the live site, and it's only creating work for them to report it.   Instead, their focus is on software being actively developed, BEFORE it goes live.

Now...if they were to point you to their site and ask.....it would be awesome to be able to rattle them off immediately.

Comment: Thank you sir, yea I don't want to appear like that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I am a hiring manager and I do like it when candidates show initiative. However it must come across as humble, not overly pedantic, and not with over confidence or in a gloating manner.

I have also had candidates report a bug when in fact they just disagreed with the UX. Thus for each bug evaluate its severity, show why it is a bug (screenshots, etc), and then steps to reproduce. This at least will show a positive attitude and gives a detailed response which helps their engineers replicate and fix said bug if needed.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the main issue with raising "bugs" in this situation is that you have no idea what their testing scope for the site was. You don't know which browsers/devices it was developed for, you don't know which versions of those browsers were supported at the time it was written, you don't know any of the business logic behind what was done or why.

Without knowing what criteria you are testing against, how do you know if the site passes or fails? A QA who is going to raise issues that they consider to be bugs which are, in fact, outside their testing scope could be problematic. It's a waste of your time as a QA to be testing things that are out of scope, and it's a waste of whoever's time the ticket gets assigned to who (at the very least) has to point out that what you're testing is out of scope. While you might view this as being pro-active, it could be a red flag that you're going to be spending your time digging into things you haven't been asked to look into, without the context you'd need to understand them, and creating unnecessary extra work for your team as a result.

The other issue, as the other answers have touched upon, is that you risk appearing to be negatively critiquing the work of the people who are hiring you. This is definitely a double-edged sword. You want to appear knowledgeable but you definitely run the risk of appearing condescending. Many people don't really take criticism well, and if the people in the room were responsible for the work you're criticising, fair or not, that's unlikely to go down well for you.

I would say it's reasonable to prepare a response in case they ask you to critique their site (but temper your language so that it doesn't come across too negatively, and maybe just flag one or two issues even if you find dozens), but I probably wouldn't offer this critique unrequested.